# Converting class GPUImageBilateralFilter in GPUImage from iOS to Android

Tags: android, ios

I want to convert class GPUImageBilateralFilter from iOS (GPUImage library) to Android. 
I created VERTEXT and FRAGMENT SHADER base on that class from iOS but i don't know to do after because i don't know iOS program. How can I do ? Any suggest for me

Update: in file .m extension has snippet code:

```html
@implementation GPUImageBilateralFilter

@synthesize distanceNormalizationFactor = _distanceNormalizationFactor;

- (id)init;
{
    
    if (!(self = [super initWithFirstStageVertexShaderFromString:kGPUImageBilateralBlurVertexShaderString
                              firstStageFragmentShaderFromString:kGPUImageBilateralFilterFragmentShaderString
                               secondStageVertexShaderFromString:kGPUImageBilateralBlurVertexShaderString
                             secondStageFragmentShaderFromString:kGPUImageBilateralFilterFragmentShaderString])) {
        return nil;
    }
    
    firstDistanceNormalizationFactorUniform  = [filterProgram uniformIndex:@"distanceNormalizationFactor"];
    secondDistanceNormalizationFactorUniform = [filterProgram uniformIndex:@"distanceNormalizationFactor"];

    self.texelSpacingMultiplier = 4.0;
    self.distanceNormalizationFactor = 8.0;

    
    return self;
}
 #pragma mark -
 #pragma mark Accessors

- (void)setDistanceNormalizationFactor:(CGFloat)newValue
{
    _distanceNormalizationFactor = newValue;
    
    [self setFloat:newValue
        forUniform:firstDistanceNormalizationFactorUniform
           program:filterProgram];    
    [self setFloat:newValue
        forUniform:secondDistanceNormalizationFactorUniform
           program:secondFilterProgram];
}
@end
```

And in .h extension has:

```html
#import "GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter.h"

@interface GPUImageBilateralFilter : GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter
{
    CGFloat firstDistanceNormalizationFactorUniform;
    CGFloat secondDistanceNormalizationFactorUniform;
}
// A normalization factor for the distance between central color and sample color.
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) CGFloat distanceNormalizationFactor;
@end
```

How can I convert that to Android

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Why would you port an iOS API class to Android? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you missing specific features in the Android API? If yes, which ones? Besides that, have a great day!

Comment: Thanks for read my question. I used GPUImage library in Android to make my images more beauty. I used GPUImageGaussianBlur to make blur but that filter make blur all region image. And i known bilateral filter in iOS which tries to blur similar color values while preserving sharp edges.

P/S: sorry my english not well

Comment: Please extend your question with what exactly you have tried already (code snippets!), and what exact problems (errors?) you are having.

Comment: @bkit4u, can you post how did you do it?

Comment: @ttotto, my code here: https://gist.github.com/bkitduy/81bb3f0dc521c119fe79